# Is it possible based on CSS to create a circle with gradient border and transparent inner?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I'm trying to create a ***circle with CSS*** that has a ***gradient border*** but also a ***transparent inner*** so that it looks like this:

[image]

There are solutions to create a gradient border if the inner is not transparent, which my below snippet is based on, but they work in principle by overlaying a one-coloured div over the gradient.

**[>>JSFIDDLE<<](https://jsfiddle.net/7uaL5u8o/)**

**>>SNIPPET<<**

```css
#cont{
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, crimson 0%, #f90 100%);
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border-radius: 1000px;
padding: 5px;
}

#box{
background: #fff;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border-radius: 1000px;
}

#example {

background: url(http://blogs.taz.de/hausblog/files/2017/12/20171208_FB_reuters2.png);
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
<div id="cont">
<div id="box"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about using the same background as your "example" div?. If I replace `background: #fff` with `background: url(http://blogs.taz.de/hausblog/files/2017/12/20171208_FB_reuters2.png)` in your example, it seems to work. You might need to futz with `background-position` to get it to line up correctly though, so I didn't want to answer completely.

Comment: Thanks Mike. It's actually a bit more complicated on the actual page (circle being on a transparent div that is again on top of a background img), so this work-around wouldnt work.

Comment: There is no reason to include the link to JS Fiddle because you've already done the right thing and created a Code Snippet right here.

Comment: @ScottMarcus people here sometimes were annoyed if there was no JSFIDDLE for them to play around and I can understand from a convenience perspective.

Comment: No one is going to ask you for a Fiddle if you include a working Code Snippet. You can play around in a code snippet even more easily because you don't need to leave the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way is [linear-gradient](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_grad_linear.asp) with SVG. The idea is to create a circle and fill its stroke with a gradient.

```css
body {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1026/800/800);
}

text {
  font-size:8em
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 200 200' width=150 height=150>
  <!-- define the gradient -->
  <defs>
    <!-- x1,y1,x2,y2 are used to define the gradient direction -->
    <linearGradient id="linear" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="60%">
      <!-- start color at 0%-->
      <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="crimson"/>
      <!-- end color at 100%-->
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f90"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <!-- Create an svg circle at [100,100] with radius of 90
       make the border-width 6 (stroke-width) fill it with gradient (stroke)
       and make the content of circle transparent (fill)
  --->
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="90" stroke="url(#linear)" stroke-width="6" fill="transparent" />
  <!-- Create a text element at the postion [70,140] -->
  <text x="70" y="140" fill="white">7</text>
</svg>
```

That you can also use as background:

```css
body {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1026/800/800);
}

#count {
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="150" height="150"><defs><linearGradient id="linear" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="60%"><stop offset="0%"   stop-color="crimson"/><stop offset="100%" stop-color="%23f90"/></linearGradient></defs><circle cx="100" cy="100" r="90" stroke="url(%23linear)" stroke-width="6" fill="transparent" /></svg>') no-repeat;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 8em;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="count">
  7
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Now you can rely on `mask` to get this effect without using SVG:

```css
body {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1026/800/800);
}

#count{
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 8em;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position:relative;
}

#count::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:linear-gradient(crimson,#f90);
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side, transparent calc(100% - 8px),#fff 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="count">
  7
</div>
```

Related: [Border Gradient with Border Radius](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51496204/8620333)

Comment: Impressive Temani! I dont understand svg code tbh - could you elaborate on the code provided so I could tailor it to my needs? Thanks so much!!!

Comment: @AlphaX yes sure ;) i will add more comments :)

Comment: @AlphaX i added more comment and a link ... you will only need to adjust the gradient color if needed and change the height/width of the SVG .. same thing with background ... as you can see i used the same svg code and put it as background image

Comment: Thank you so much Temani! I really didnt think it would be possible! I will have a read and amend as needed!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a CodePen example: (https://codepen.io/lazercaveman/pen/rNKbxdq) of how to solve this (or something similar) using CSS and implement a fully transparent loading spinner with angular gradient using CSS.

```
.spinner-icon {
  &:before {
    background-image: conic-gradient(
      transparent 72deg,
      #fff 360deg
    );
    mask: radial-gradient(
      farthest-side,
      transparent calc(100% - 12px),
      #fff 0
    );
  }
}

.bg-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(217deg, rgba(255,0,0,.8), rgba(255,0,0,0) 70.71%),
            linear-gradient(127deg, rgba(0,255,0,.8), rgba(0,255,0,0) 70.71%),
            linear-gradient(336deg, rgba(0,0,255,.8), rgba(0,0,255,0) 70.71%);
  border-radius: 12px;
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the color of the inner `div` to match the surrounding background and populate the inner `div` with data that is vertically and horizontally aligned to the middle (there are many ways to do that, I'm doing it in a "down and dirty" way here).

```css
#cont{
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, crimson 0%, #f90 100%);
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border-radius: 1000px;
padding: 5px;
}

#box{
background: url(http://blogs.taz.de/hausblog/files/2017/12/20171208_FB_reuters2.png);
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border-radius: 1000px;
text-align:center;
font-size:7em;
color:#FFF;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
font-family:Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#example {

background: url(http://blogs.taz.de/hausblog/files/2017/12/20171208_FB_reuters2.png);
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
<div id="cont">
<div id="box">7</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ... Pretty sure that's exactly what I said in my comment, and the OP said that it wasn't working for him...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I didn't see your comment, but if this doesn't work for the OP, then he should explain his situation more clearly so we can more accurately help him.

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you. However, my starting solution already has a coloured inner, whilst the solution I need requires a transparent inner as per my original post. I start to feel confirmed that it's not possible with CSS and I may have to create an image with photoshop instead

Comment: @AlphaX Can you explain why you must have a transparent background? Isn't the goal to get the look you showed?